# What is the etymology of saying "when" to stop pouring or serving?

Tags: colloquialisms

I was wondering: What is the origin of asking someone to say "when" (to mean "enough") while they are serving food or beverages?

Comment: I've always assumed it to mean 'tell me when to stop pouring'.

Comment: I've always supposed that it started as a joke based on something like "I'll tell you when that's enough".

Comment: You don't ask someone to say the word *when*, you ask them to tell you the time to do it. "Say when..." is merely a phrasing for that request. Answering with a literal *when* is merely a little joke.

Comment: It depends on the person who's pouring the liquid saying "Say when" (a short way to ask the other to tell them when to stop, as @KateBunting said), and this being facetiously interpreted as "Say 'when' ".

Comment: NB Also, when being sworn in, you should not repeat *I, state your name* when the bailiff prompts *I, state your name*.

Comment: ***Say when*** - 
a formula used when pouring someone else a drink, i.e. say when you want me to stop pouring. https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/kroro3q#hf32opa

Comment: Bryan, you can ask (excellent) questions like this, on the ELL site, which is made for the purpose.